# How is the eye of the Longclaw getting opened?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Game of thrones Season 7 episode 6 , when John snow is coming up from cold water after killing some undead the eyes of the long claw(his sword) is getting opened. Approx time frame (52:24-52:29)

[image]

[image]